# Day/Hour Heatmap + mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, d3.js

I'm trying to fit my dataset into the example here: (http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084).

Here's my d3js:

```
     var margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30 },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 430 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24),
      legendElementWidth = gridSize*2,
      buckets = 9,
      colors =     ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#25 3494","#081d58"], // alternatively colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9]
      days = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
      times = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a", "11a", "12a", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p", "12p"];


d3.json("/test/heatmap.php", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    day= +d.day;
    hour= +d.hour;
    value= +d.value;
});
    },
    function(error, data) {
      var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
          .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })])
          .range(colors);
          console.log(d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; }))
          ;
console.log("test");

      var svg = d3.select(".wpd3-8-3").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
          .data(days)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
            .attr("class", function (d, i) { return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis"); });

      var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
          .data(times)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .attr("y", 0)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
            .attr("class", function(d, i) { return ((i >= 7 && i <= 16)      ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis"); });

      var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.day - 1) * gridSize; })
          .attr("rx", 4)
          .attr("ry", 4)
          .attr("class", "hour bordered")
          .attr("width", gridSize)
          .attr("height", gridSize)
          .style("fill", colors[0]);

      heatMap.transition().duration(1000)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });

      heatMap.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.value; });

      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
          .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) {      return d; })
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend");

      legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
        .attr("height", gridSize / 2)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

      legend.append("text")
        .attr("class", "mono")
        .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height + gridSize);
  });
```

And an example of my php echo:

```
[{"day":"4","hour":"0","value":"91"},{"day":"7","hour":"0","value":"93"},{"day":"3","hour":"1","value":"71"},{"day":"4","hour":"1","value":"90"},{"day":"3","hour":"2","value":"96"},{"day":"4","hour":"2","value":"89"},{"day":"5","hour":"2","value":"88"},{"day":"3","hour":"3","value":"97"},{"day":"4","hour":"3","value":"88"},{"day":"5","hour":"3","value":"88"},{"day":"6","hour":"3","value":"89"},{"day":"4","hour":"4","value":"86"},{"day":"5","hour":"4","value":"86"},{"day":"6","hour":"4","value":"88"},{"day":"7","hour":"4","value":"91"},{"day":"4","hour":"5","value":"86"},{"day":"6","hour":"5","value":"88"},{"day":"7","hour":"5","value":"91"},{"day":"6","hour":"6","value":"88"},{"day":"7","hour":"6","value":"91"},{"day":"6","hour":"7","value":"86"},{"day":"6","hour":"8","value":"86"},{"day":"6","hour":"9","value":"86"},{"day":"6","hour":"10","value":"86"},{"day":"6","hour":"11","value":"85"},{"day":"3","hour":"12","value":"91"},{"day":"4","hour":"12","value":"82"},{"day":"5","hour":"12","value":"82"},{"day":"6","hour":"12","value":"84"},{"day":"4","hour":"13","value":"82"},{"day":"6","hour":"13","value":"85"},{"day":"6","hour":"14","value":"87"},{"day":"6","hour":"15","value":"88"},{"day":"6","hour":"16","value":"88"},{"day":"6","hour":"17","value":"88"},{"day":"6","hour":"18","value":"88"},{"day":"6","hour":"19","value":"89"},{"day":"6","hour":"20","value":"90"},{"day":"6","hour":"21","value":"91"},{"day":"6","hour":"22","value":"91"},{"day":"6","hour":"23","value":"93"}]
```

I am stumped, because when I log the results of the d3.json, it matches the results of the example file. The thing I've noticed is in the example, the

```
console.log(d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; }))
```

loads with the max value. When I load my values, console.log doesn't seem to print beyond the d3.json step.

Any advice? I'm a bit stumped after a few days of reading and experimenting.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don'T, but looking at the tool I will use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 functions in the json call (one for the error and one for the success?). You only need one - you first check if the error is there and do an error handling.

So you could remove this

```
function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        day= +d.day;
        hour= +d.hour;
        value= +d.value;
    });
},
```

Apart from that, it's mostly good - just that you'll need to adjust the x attr  call a bit - you don't need the -1

```
 .attr("x", function (d) { return (d.hour) * gridSize; })
```

Comment: I did notice that it looked like I was declaring a function "data" twice. I tried naming the first one "data2" but it didn't seem to work. You're saying to remove the second function(error,data) all together?

Comment: The first function (i.e. the 2nd parameter). You have all your code in the 2nd function.

Comment: Yes, I removed the second function altogether, and it is somewhat working.

Comment: d3.json("/test/heatmap.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        day= +d.day;
        hour= +d.hour;
        value= +d.value;
    });
          var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()

Comment: ah ok. I thought you were talking about removing the whole function body too :-). All good now?

Comment: All good. Data is loaded, just running into formatting issues now. Trying to work around some of the color scales. Appreciate your help✌. Sometimes the answer is right I front of your eyes!